# Aligning Vertices Diagonally

Tags: modeling, transforms, vertices

I'm trying to make a pistol with a hammer thingy on the back. I've been struggling to make the back perfectly aligned like the red line in the 3rd image. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think the **Shear** tool should work:

- Select all the vertices of your twisted face.
- Press <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> so that they all collapse on the same Y axis.
- Switch to the right orthographic view, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> and move your mouse to change the shear angle until the angle your need (press -1 for a 45° angle).
- It should be good.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is 1 solution to this that I could come up with.

Select all these back vertices and scale to 0 in the appropriate axis (it looks like it's the Y axis on your screenshot). That will align them perfectly. Then you could set the 3D cursor at the topmost vertex. Set the pivot point to 3D Cursor. Then having all these back vertices still selected go to Mesh > Transform > Shear or use Shift+Ctrl+Alt+S. And move your mouse to shear the desired amount. (You can hit X or Y while shearing to shear along the appropriate axis).

I should add that you need to be in the appropriate orthographic 3D view to shear it properly. If you shear in a perspective view it might get wonky.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

- custom orientation axes
- 3d cursor as pivot for rotation/scaling

  1. Create (if you don't have it yet) a plane where you want all the points to be (It's the diagonal plane on which the red line lay).
  2. Select that plane and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then select *Cursor to Selected*, now press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> to create a new set of orientation axes with the Z axis perpendicular to the plane.
  3. Select the Cursor as the pivot for rotation/scaling (You can do it just pressing <kbd>.</kbd>).
  4. Press <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> again to scale on the Z axis of your orientation axes, then press <kbd>0</kbd> to scale the points of 0 and put them on the plane.

Comment: You don't _have_ to create a plane to make the custom orientation .. you can just select three vertices which define it... and while this method flattens the vertices nicely on to the right plane, it can throw the horizontal (Y direction) edges.

Comment: You're right! Your solution is better!

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you already have 2 parallel edges which define the plane you want to flatten to, so you can:

- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> extend the vertices not on the plane out beyond it
- <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> use the Knife tool (with Z to cut through) to cut between the good edges
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide the protruding vertices back on to the straightened ones (all in one move)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> > <kbd>R</kbd> Vertex Menu > Remove doubles.

(For ease of <kbd>C</kbd> circle selection, all in the front view, with 'Limit Selection to Visible' switched off.)

[image]