# Align vertex into a straight line non paralel to an axis

Tags: vertices

I have two faces, the should make a straight plane, but I want to keep the mesh without Ngons. Is there a way in which I can align the 3 (6 counting the ones behind) vertices into doing a straight line non parallel to an axis?

[image: The vertex are aligned by hand]

Answer (score 1):

I have realized what can be done. Scale it on the z axis to 0, and then rotate the whole selection.

Comment: or rather use the Shear tool: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116183/aligning-vertices-diagonally/116202#116202